# How to save multiple products to a single column order by user in order table in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

this is my controller i just want to save multiple product ids to a single column name seleted products  i did not find the solution please help me to sove this isse

```
public function applee(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        //
     ]); 
 
     if (Auth::check()){

    $apple = new Apples();
    $userId = Auth::id();

    $apple->user_id = auth('api')->user()->id;;
    $apple-> transaction_id =  $request->transaction_id;
    $apple->buyer_name =  $request->buyer_name;
    $apple-> address =  $request->address;
    $apple->  phone =  $request->phone;
    $apple-> email =  $request->email;

    $apple-> city =  $request->city;
    $apple-> payment_method =  $request->payment_method;
    $apple->   plan_id =  $request->plan_id;
    $apple-> selected_products_ids =  $request->selected_products_ids;
    $apple->   plan_purchase_date = $request->plan_purchase_date;


    $apple->content = $request->content;

    $apple->save();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
    ], 201);
}
```

Comment: Save all product `id` in `selected_products_ids` column, also you can save as data as json. If its an array then,  change `$request->selected_products_ids` to `$request->selected_products_ids[]`

Comment: Save it in serialized array https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php check this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as a `text` column. or if you use MySQL you can set it as `JSON` column. But I recommend that you create a DB relation between apples and products table. and later on, use the [Many to many realtionship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) included in Laravel.

if you do that correctly, you can use something like that:

```php
$apple->products()->sync($selected_products_ids);
```